# last-child for class not working

Tags: css, class, html

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='item'>
        <div class='date'>
            <a></a>
        </div>
        <div class='work'>
            <a></a>
        </div>
        <div class='info'>
            <a>$row[info]</a>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div id="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have border-bottom for class info:

```
.info {padding-bottom: 10px;  border-bottom: 1px dashed #C8C8C8;}
```

But I dont want border for last child but it is not working. All borders disappears.

```
.info:last-child {border-bottom: none;}
```

Why is that? And what is the best solution?

Comment: are they placed correctly in the css file? .info should come first and then .info:last-child

Comment: i can see your code working here http://jsfiddle.net/4yuUT/

Comment: All `.info` elements are the last child of their parents. What did you expect?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you're trying to achieve? Your trying to apply `:last-child` when you've only got one child to target, therefore it will not appear.

It would work if there were more than one `.info`

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/ELk4E/ - In the fiddle I've replicated div.info three times, and the 3rd and last has the `border-bottom` removed via the `:last-child`

However, if you have div.info on your page several times but within different parents, this will not work. Such as:

```
<div class='container'> <!-- parent 1 -->
    <div class='item'>
        <div class='date'>
            <a></a>
        </div>
        <div class='work'>
            <a></a>
        </div>
        <div class='info'>
            <a>Last Child</a>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div id="footer">
  </div>
</div>

<div class='container'><!-- parent 2 -->
    <div class='item'>
        <div class='date'>
            <a></a>
        </div>
        <div class='work'>
            <a></a>
        </div>
        <div class='info'>
            <a>Last Child</a>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div id="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example you could use the following CSS to remove the `border-bottom` of the last container's `div.info`:

```
.info {padding-bottom: 10px;  border-bottom: 1px dashed #C8C8C8;}
.container:last-of-type .info {border-bottom: none;}
```

Basically the :last-child selector matches every element that is the last child of its parent. See here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
.info:last-child {border-bottom: none; !important}
```

Comment: The user has only one child of the parent, therefore important will not do anything